# Do I need to to allocate memory using new before insert into a C++ STL map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have the following function which inserts pair to STL map. Do I need to to allocate memory using new before insert?

```
char* foo(char* lnumber)
{

       char* sData = “A,B,C”;
       Char delim[] = “,”;                       
       typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> TStrStrMap; 
       typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> TStrStrPair;
       TStrStrMap tMap;

       if(strstr(sData,delim) != 0)
       {
          tok = strtok( sData, delim);
          while( ( tok != NULL))
          {
             int bytes = strlen(tok)+1;
             char* ll = new char[bytes];
             memset(ll,0,bytes);
             strcpy(ll,tok);
             ll[bytes] = '\0';
             int bytes1 = strlen("yes")+1;
             char* ll1 = new char[bytes1];
             memset(ll1,0,bytes1);
             strcpy(ll1,”yes”);
             ll1[bytes1] = '\0';
             tMap.insert(TStrStrPair(ll,ll1));
             tok = strtok( NULL, delim);
          }
        }

        std::string strValue = tMap[lnumber];
        return(strdup(strValue.c_str()));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to new the memory before you insert. STL will allocate the memory and copy the object into the container.

Comment: Most of this code makes very little sense, I'm afraid. Why not write real C++ without any pointers or `new`?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question to ask how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question - no, you do not need to allocate the memory yourself given the declarations you have shown.  `std::string` will manage the memory for the string values, `std::pair` will handle the memory of its `std::string` values, and `std::map` will handle the memory for its `std::pair` values.

Your current code is leaking every `char[]` buffer that you are allocating with 'new[]'.  Your `std::string` values are making copies of the data, so you need to `delete[]` them whenyou are done with them, eg:

```
char* foo(char* lnumber)
{
    char sData[] = "A,B,C";
    char *delim = ",";                       
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> TStrStrMap; 
    typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> TStrStrPair;
    TStrStrMap tMap;

    if(strstr(sData, delim) != 0)
    {
        char *tok = strtok(sData, delim);
        while (tok != NULL)
        {
            int bytes = strlen(tok)+1;
            char* ll = new char[bytes];
            strcpy(ll, tok);
            int bytes1 = strlen("yes")+1;
            char* ll1 = new char[bytes1];
            strcpy(ll1, "yes");
            tMap.insert(TStrStrPair(ll,ll1));
            delete[] ll; // <-- here
            delete[] ll1; // <-- here
            tok = strtok( NULL, delim);
        }
    }

    std::string strValue = tMap[lnumber];
    return strdup(strValue.c_str());
}
```

With that said, since `std::string` has a constructor that accepts `char*` input, your loop code can be greatly simplified to the following:

```
// you really should be using std::string instead
// of char* for the function's input and output...
//
char* foo(char* lnumber)
{
    char sData[] = "A,B,C";
    char *delim = ",";                       
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> TStrStrMap; 
    typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> TStrStrPair;
    TStrStrMap tMap;

    char *tok = strtok(sData, delim);
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        tMap.insert(TStrStrPair(tok, "yes"));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    std::string strValue = tMap[lnumber];
    return strdup(strValue.c_str());
}
```